# Alter table migration (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Simple command is

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pages ALTER COLUMN title_txtid INT NULLABLE');
```

But every time I got error.

[image]

I have tried 'INT NULL' and similar variants. Is this something missing?

Comment: did you write this yourself,   or was this created by a doctrine:migrations:diff ?

Comment: I am working with existed database. And yes, write it by meself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE title_txtid title_txtid INT DEFAULT NULL');
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pages ALTER COLUMN title_txtid INT DEFAULT NULL');`

Comment: The same erorr, 'DROP NOT NULL' also.